# Как вывести в Qlabel картинку, путь к которой дан в Qlistview?

Tags: qt

Как вывести в Qlabel картинку, путь к которой дан в Qlistview?

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на правильность решения т.к. сам имею небольшой опыт с qt:

```
if (ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedRows().count()==0)
    return;
QModelIndex index=ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedRows().at(0);
QString str=ui->listView->model()->data(index).toString();
QPalette pal;
pal.setBrush(ui->label->backgroundRole(), QBrush(QPixmap(str)));
ui->label->setPalette(pal);
ui->label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

Только мне кажется, что лучше там использовать QListWidget, с ним код поменяются первые четыре страки вот на такие:

```
if (ui->listWidget->selectedItems().count()==0)
    return;
QString str=ui->listWidget->selectedItems().at(0)->text();
```

Comment: вот исходный кода для большего восприятия:
QDir dir;

    model = new QStringListModel(this);
pix1= new QPixmap;
QStringList  list = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(0,QObject::tr("Find Images"),QDir::homePath(), QObject::tr("JPG files (*.jpg);;PNG files (*.png);;BMP files(*.bmp);;All files (*.*)"));
model->setStringList(list);
ui->listView->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed|QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
  QString string=list.at(0);

pix1->load(string);
ui->label->setPixmap(*pix1);
ui->label->setFixedSize(640,480);

Comment: когда я открываю картинки путь к ним заносится в Qlistview, я хочу при нажатии на определенный путь чтоб в Qlable открывалась эта картинка, или же подскажите как по другому можнj листать картинки в Qlabel?

Comment: Что-то не пойму, что вам нужно - перехватить нажатие на путь? Тогда смотрите в сторону сигнала QListView::clicked( const QModelIndex & index ) (или doubleClicked, это уж как нравится, можно и оба направить в один слот), о передает индекс нажатой строки (то, что я вытаскивал из selectionModel() ). Можно ещё перехватывать сигнал на изменение выделеного. Но я бы все рано использовал QListWidget. По поводу листать по другому - посмотрите в сторону QDataWidgetMapper, но с ним я и сам не работал